# Android H.264 BaseProfile level support

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264

According to [the official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), android supports h.264 Base Profile on 3.0+ devices, however it makes no mention to which [levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels) the system will support. Does anyone know, or would this be dependent of each device?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the documentation doesn't mention any levels is the wide variety of Android devices. It works for Apple since they only offer a few models but there are many Android manufactures. Google cannot guarantee that a particular level will work across all those devices.

In fact, if you look at the [Video Encoding Recommendations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations) they can't even guarantee `2 Mbps HD 720p @ 30 fps`. It's marked `N/A on all devices`.

For `HD 720p @ 30 fps` the corresponding level is `3.1`. A device capable of playing a certain level can also play all the levels below.

This doesn't imply there are no Android devices that can play levels `3.2+` and even `Main`, `High` profiles etc. But if you need wide availability you need to target the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Google *could* choose to require that all Android 6.0+ (for example) devices support h.264 High profile, so we can stop using obsolete low-quality(per bitrate) Baseline at some point in the future.  But google chooses not to do this, reducing the quality of video on the Internet because of lowest-common-denominator compatibility with craptastic devices.  It's not rare to find Baseline 1080p 8Mbps video, because people clearly didn't think through the fact that a low-end device that only supports Baseline probably can't play a high-rez file anyway.

Comment: But VP9 is supported from Android 4.4+, and HEVC on Android 5.0+, so those are the highest quality-per-bitrate codecs that are guaranteed available on Android.